# sqlcmd won't work on ubuntu despite standard installation and usage

Tags: sql-server, shell, odbc

I followed the instructions on the MS site and installed tools including sqlcmd.

I followed the examples, with several variants

```
sqlcmd -H 12.34.56.78,1234 -U $user -P $passwd -d $database -Q "SELECT * FROM blodge"

sqlcmd -S 12.34.56.78,1234 -U $user -P $passwd -d $database -Q "SELECT * FROM blodge"

sqlcmd -S tsp:12.34.56.78,1234 -U $user -P $passwd -d $database -Q "SELECT * FROM blodge"
```

and got errors like

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'muggins'..

and

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Protocol error in TDS stream.
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection due to prelogin failure.

[Note I have changed URL, etc, above.  Also, I checked that all the login details are correct]

Thanks for any help [open to alternatives to sqlcmd also!]
P.S. I have tested the connection from the GUI MySQL client
PPS Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Are you trying to use sqlcmd with mysql or is this question wrongly tagged?

Comment: I am trying to access an SQL server which is accessible using at least one MySQL (GUI) client I have tried.

Comment: Do you mean you are accessing a MYSQL Server or Microsofts SQLServer?

Answer (score 0):

The correct format is the second one:

```
sqlcmd -S 12.34.56.78,1234 -U $user -P $passwd -d $database -Q "SELECT * FROM blodge"
```

The default SQL Server port is 1433, but as you seem to reach SQL Server ("Login failed for user.."), double check your username/password or try to leave out the `-P` parameter from the command so you see if you get the password prompt.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.  It didn't work.  A mystery.  I ended up solving this using a python script instead.

Comment: @DavidE Did you get the password prompt when you left out the `-P` switch?

Comment: Yes, that part was fine.  It just didn't want to authenticate, even though the password I used works for that server if I use other applications.